# Ionic return a specific array item from JSON array

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ecmascript-6

I would like to retrieve a speicific array element from a returned JSON request. So far I can get the whole feed, but I am struggling how to restrict it to a specific element.

So far I have this in my service controller;

```
getJsonData(){
    return this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/.json').map(res => res.json());
}
```

In my page I have;

```
getdata() { 
    this.HttpModule.getJsonData().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.News= result.data.children(1);
        console.log("success:"+this.News);
      },
      err => {
        console.error("Error : "+err);
      },  
      () => {
        console.log("getData completed");
      }
    );
    }
```

It should be `children` by I tried `children(1)` as a guess but it didn't work

Comment: Did you try parsing your result to object with `JSON.Parse` and then accessing children[1]?

Answer (score 1):

The `children` property is an array,  and in javascript to access array items you use `[]` (the bracket notation).

So use

```
this.News= result.data.children[1];
```

---

*Also note that arrays in javascript are zero-based so the `[1]` will return the 2nd element*

Comment: This is the first thing I tried, unfortunatly this does not work: TypeError: result.data.children is not a function

Comment: @RedCrusador just to make sure, you used ***square brackets*** `[]`  and not ***parenthesis*** `()` and you still got the error about *not a function* ?

Comment: Yes thats what I got back, they are [ ]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming result.data is array .
we can do

```
for ( let item of result.data)
{
   console.log(item.field1);
   console.log(item.field2);

}
```

Comment: Yes say if I want the 1000 th element does that mean I have to iterate through the 999 items to get there?